# Extracting Date Parts and storing as text value - Month and Day need to reflect no leading zeros

Tags: sql-server

I need to take today's date and convert it to store the month as an integer + "." + the day as an integer + "." + the year

So if the DATE() = 01/04/1965 i need to store it as 1.4.1965
So if the DATE() = 12/25/1965 i need to store it as 12.25.1965

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 2012+, you can use the **Format()** function.  For Example

(assuming GetDate() = 2017-02-03 19:31:32.140)

```
Select Format(GetDate(),'M.d.yyyy') -- 2.3.2017
```